# Handling special characters with Twilio and AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, twilio, aws-api-gateway

I have set up a Twilio SMS POST webhook that calls an AWS API Gateway endpoint. On the API Gateway side, I am set up as such:

Integration Request:

- Type: Lambda function
- Mapping Templates: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
#set($httpPost = $input.path('$').split("&"))
{
#foreach( $kvPair in $httpPost )
 #set($kvTokenised = $kvPair.split("="))
 #if( $kvTokenised.size() > 1 )
   "$kvTokenised[0]" : "$kvTokenised[1]"#if( $foreach.hasNext ),
   #end
 #else
   "$kvTokenised[0]" : ""#if( $foreach.hasNext ),
   #end
 #end
#end
}
```

The above provides my AWS Lambda handler an `event` that is JSONified.

My Lambda function basically reads in the `event` and does some processing to it. The problem is, when I send a text to my Twilio phone number as such:

> Hey there!

the Lambda interprets as such:

> Hey+there%21

How do I handle special characters/emojis to come through as they should? The same thing is happening with phone numbers (+1XXXXXXXXXX) turning into (%2BXXXXXXXXXX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have turned the keys and values from the url encoded request into what looks like a JSON object, but you didn't decode the url encoded values.

I think you need to use [`$util.urlDecode()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference) on the keys and values to ensure that the data is all plain text.

Try:

```
#set($httpPost = $input.path('$').split("&"))
{
#foreach( $kvPair in $httpPost )
 #set($kvTokenised = $kvPair.split("="))
 #if( $kvTokenised.size() > 1 )
   "$util.urlDecode($kvTokenised[0])" : "$util.urlDecode($kvTokenised[1])"#if( $foreach.hasNext ),
   #end
 #else
   "$util.urlDecode($kvTokenised[0])" : ""#if( $foreach.hasNext ),
   #end
 #end
#end
}
```